# php PDO repetable read isolation level

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

i want to create a transaction with repeatable read isolation level using PDO in a MySQL Database. I think i found a way but i want to tell me if this is the right way.

I will set PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT to false and the i will use native mysql commands to begin the trasaction, commit it and if needed rollback

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("START TRANSACTION;");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ");

$stmt->execute();

...(some other commands)....

$stmt = $conn->prepare("COMMIT");

$stmt->execute();
```

also do i need the first command saying "START TRANSACTION"?

Comment: ['PDO::beginTransaction'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)

Comment: I presume that, if you change per-session transaction settings _after_ you start a transaction, it won't apply to that transaction.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, that is correct. You need to change the transaction isolation level _before_ starting the transaction. The way the code is written above, it will only apply to the _next_ transaction in that session.

Comment: Also, repeatable read is the default anyway. So this set isolation level command will have no effect, unless the OP has deliberately changed the default.